# Viewport resolution downscaling option for Eevee and Workbench

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, workbench-render-engine

Currently I have a laptop (4GB ram ; Intel i5 2.5GHz ; no graphic card). I want to use Blender 2.93 on my separate 1080p monitor but this introduces a problem : the Blender viewport is incredibly laggy on the monitor. Unlike that, the 2.79 version works perfectly smooth.

I have to shrink the window/panel size down for the refresh rate to catch up, but then it will be inconvenient. Answers to questions similar to this usually points at the pixel size option in Cycles, but I'd like to have this feature implemented in other two engines too, especially for Workbench.

If there's a kind of plugin that can help me with this, please recommend. I'd appreciate if someone would write a feature request for this.